# ¿Como Crear Una Carpeta En OneDrive?

Tags: android

Estoy utilizando la sdk de OndeDrive para realizar algunas pruebas y quiero saber si es posible crear una carpeta desde mi app a OneDrive. Me dan una mano por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, es posible. **Usando el SDK** puedes crear la carpeta dentro de una colección de elementos mediante el uso de los constructores de solicitud `getDrive`,`getItems`, y `getChildren` con el método `create`.

Parámetros

|Name|Description|

|----|-----------|

|*folderToCreate*|La carpeta que quieres crear.|

**Ejemplo:**

```
final String parentId = "0000000000000000000000";
final Item folderToCreate = new Item();
folderToCreate.name = "NewFolder";
folderToCreate.folder = new Folder();

final ICallback<Item> callback = new ICallback<Item> {
    @Override
    public void success(final Item result) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Created Folder", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    ...
    // Handle failure
}

oneDriveClient
    .getDrive()
    .getItems(parentId)
    .getChildren()
    .buildRequest()
    .create(folderToCreate, callback);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.